# Video not play or autoplay in chrome, even muted - sometimes yes, sometimes no

Tags: html, angular, html5-video

I can't find a solution for this. Sorry to put angular and html as tags - it's because I've no clue who is the guilted.

Yes, I saw on Stack Overflow and many others sources that a video "muted" basically has no restrictions. But in my scenario... well, sometimes it works, sometimes it's not works...sometimes I do a refresh and it's works.

Very random.

```
<video *ngIf="p.background.type==='video'" [ngStyle]="{opacity: p.background.backgroundOpacity}"
           class="backgroundElement" src="../assets/backgrounds/videos/{{p.background.file}}"
           [ngClass]="{currentVideo: i === this.pageIndex}"
           muted loop></video>

const video = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.currentVideo').play();
      if (video !== undefined) {
          video.then(_ => {
             console.log('worked at this time');
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
      }, 2000);
```

The error I got from promise is : message: "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

But it's a muted video. So, any suggestion ?

Comment: use `muted="muted"` instead of only `muted` in your video tag.

Comment: did this already...no luck

Comment: is it possible to create a demo stackblitz.com for this? it would attract more people to your question.